# Adding text tool to drawing app HTML, Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

I'm trying to add a text tool to my [drawing app](https://codepen.io/pedrovil/pen/wJPJmO) I'm developing using a input box.

Is it possible to apply the text to the canvas pressing enter key or clicking outside the box and destroy the input box?

**HTML**

```
<span id="tools">
  <button id="text" class="texttool">txt</button>
</span>

<canvas id="sketch"></canvas>
```

**JS**

```
    var canvas, ctx;
    var inputBox=0;

    function drawText(ctx,x,y,size) {
    if (inputBox==0){
        inputBox=1;
          var input = new CanvasInput({
              x: mouseX,
              y: mouseY,
              canvas: document.getElementById('sketch'),
              fontSize: 18,
              fontFamily: 'Arial',
              fontColor: '#212121',
              fontWeight: 'bold',
              width: 300,
              padding: 8,
              borderWidth: 1,
              borderColor: '#000',
              borderRadius: 3,
              boxShadow: '1px 1px 0px #fff',
              innerShadow: '0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
              placeHolder: 'Enter message here...'
              });
          }
    }

    function init() {
        canvas = document.getElementById('sketch');
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

        if (canvas.getContext)
            ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        if (ctx) {
            canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', sketch_mouseDown, false);
            canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', sketch_mouseMove, false);
            window.addEventListener('mouseup', sketch_mouseUp, false);
        }
    }

    var onTool = function() {

        if ( tool == 'brush' )
        {   drawLine(ctx,mouseX,mouseY,2); }

        else if ( tool == 'eraser' )
        {   drawEraser(ctx,mouseX,mouseY,2); }

        else if ( tool == 'text' )
        {   drawText(ctx,mouseX,mouseY,2); }
    };
```

Comment: Make it easier, try to give a css style to the box that makes the borders invisible

Answer (score 0):

You can change your drawText function to hide the border of your box.

This is an easy solution, that will look like there is no box, but you wont see it when created either.

Change `innerShadow: '0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',` with `innerShadow: '0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',` and also change `borderWidth: 1` to 0

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I need to somehow draw the text to the canvas and that way I cannot use other tools properly, neither I can't reuse the text tooI I guess.